# How to access Firebase's method channel to mock with setMockMethodCallHandler?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Trying to mock Firebase in the test but can't figure out how to access Firebase's method channel with the latest API version, when upgrading firebase_core_platform_interface from v4.4.0 to v4.5.2.

How do you get access to Firebase’s Method Channel to pass into XXX in setMockMethodCallHandler to mock Firebase?

```
TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger.setMockMethodCallHandler(XXX, (call) {...});
```

Current pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_core: ^2.4.1
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.2
```

We used to be able to mock Firebase when we had firebase_core_platform_interface 4.4.0, but can't figure how how to get the equivalent of `MethodChannelFirebase.channel` with the newer API version for Firebase. The code below is what used to work with the old Firebase version:

```
MethodChannelFirebase.channel.setMockMethodCallHandler((call) {...});
```